# Signalr 2.1.1 OnConnected not firing even with client callbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Hub code:

```
    private readonly IHubContext<IMyHubClient> _context;

    public MyHub(IHubContext<IMyHubClient> context)
    {
      _context = context;
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

        //some code to store connected user info

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

Client code:

```
        $.connection.myHub.client.connected = function() { alert('1'); };
        $.connection.myHub.client.disconnected = function() { alert('2'); };
        $.connection.hub.start()
                  .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id); })
                  .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not Connect!'); });
```

Client succesfully connects to hub and js callbacks are working. But server-side OnConnected method never fires. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Is `MyHub` getting constructed? I doub't SignalR is able to supply the `IHubContext<IMyHubClient>` parameter. If you add a parameterless constructor or remove the existing one, your code should work.

Comment: I Use SignalR, after moving the test i wrote long ago, i update the hub from 2.0 to 2.1, and wrote lot changes, BTW, i had issue with connecting users, so i rewrite lots of codes, and replace the user management part with very simple code, what i got, now, and i understand, is that my constructor and the OnConnect, wont get called for second user, once the first user got connected :|